# JSplitPane overlaps JButtons in BorderLayout, but does not when layout is null

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jsplitpane, border-layout

So I'm having another issue.....

I'm currently using a BorderLayout in my GUI so that when I resize my jframe, all of the internal components resize with it. I couldn't get any other layout to work with how I want the GUI to look while providing this resizing capability. At the top I have a JMenuBar, and below it I have a bunch of buttons. Below that I am supposed to have a JSplitPane, and it is there. However, the buttons seemed to be contained within the JSplitPane, which is not my intention. So when anything happens within the splitpane, the buttons disappear until I move my mouse over them again.

When I set my layout to null everything works great except I lose the resizing capability, which is not good.

Tried posting images but it wont let me since my rep isnt at 10 yet :(

Any suggestions?
I've tried putting the buttons into a JPanel then adding the jpanel but the splitpane overlaps with that. Same with a JToolBar.

The order in which I add my items is:

1) the menu bar

```
setJMenuBar(menuBar)
```

2) the buttons

```
getContentPane().add(btnZoomIn)
```

etc.

3) the split pane

```
getContentPane().add(splitPane)
```

then the rest of the things you see after that

Comment: Got some code that demonstrates the problem? Or Screen shot?  From the looks of it, you should be adding you buttons to `getContentPane().add(btnZoomIn, BorderLayout.NORTH)` as border layout only allows one component to reside within the center position of the UI

Comment: here's the null layout
http://imgur.com/1X1h7

here's the border layout
http://imgur.com/xMQUm

also, in response to the borderlayout.north: i've switched it so that i add each of my 6 buttons to a jtoolbar and then added that at the north spot, and that did the trick. my buttons looks odd now because theyre in the tool bar, but oh well. thanks for the suggestion! it helped a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work fine for me...

[image]

```
public class BadLayout06 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BadLayout06();
    }

    public BadLayout06() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
                mb.add(new JMenu("File"));

                JToolBar tb = new JToolBar();
                tb.add(new JButton("Zoom In"));
                tb.add(new JButton("Zoom Out"));
                tb.add(new JButton("Invert Image"));
                tb.add(new JButton("Toggle Highlights"));
                tb.add(new JButton("Save"));
                tb.add(new JButton("Cancel"));
                tb.setFloatable(false);

                JSplitPane spSub = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
                JTabbedPane tpLeft = new JTabbedPane();
                tpLeft.add("Table Entry", new JPanel());
                tpLeft.add("Form Entry", new JPanel());
                spSub.setLeftComponent(tpLeft);
                JTabbedPane tpRight = new JTabbedPane();
                tpRight.add("Field Help", new JPanel());
                tpRight.add("Image Navigation", new JPanel());
                spSub.setRightComponent(tpRight);


                JSplitPane spMain = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
                spMain.setLeftComponent(new JPanel());
                spMain.setRightComponent(spSub);


                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setJMenuBar(mb);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(tb, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                frame.add(spMain, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: yes, adding the jtoolbar in the north position worked for me. thanks!